# How can I remove jQuery in js folder from Magento layout

Tags: layout, jquery, extensions

I have added this code to remove jQuery.1.6.4 in my js folder. But it does not remove Jquery.

In my local.xml file I've put:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>js/VS/jquery-1.6.4.min.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

But this is not working.

Comment: put full xml code...

Comment: are you want to remove from either all or a specific page??

Comment: tell me  file path location???

Comment: js folder in localhost/magento/js it's my path

Comment: is file dir localhost/magento/js/VS/jquery-1.6.4.min.js right?

Comment: Yes it's my path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
js/VS/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

to:

```
VS/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

If you want to remove it from all pages then your local.xml code should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>VS/jquery-1.6.4.min.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Not Working Yarr

Comment: put full local.xml code in question

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
<remove name="cart_sidebar"></remove>
 <remove name="tags_popular"></remove>
 <remove name="left.blog.menu"></remove>
 
 
 
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>VS/jquery-1.6.4.min.js</name></action>
    
  <!-- <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery_min.js</script></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-no-conflict.js</script></action>-->
       
  </reference>
  
  

  <reference name="left">
  <remove name="currency" />
  </reference>
</default>
</layout>`

Comment: I am adding for remove css then it's Working

Comment: My code is `<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>`

Comment: Then What's issue this css in skin folder. i am remove jquery from js folder. means removeItem remove js or css from only skin folder?

Comment: example of remove and add js http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2014/09/magento-add-or-remove-js.html

Answer (score 0):

I am Found Blog to add and remove js in magento

I am aslo get this code also. i share this link here for better answer for this

[add and Remove Js In magento](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2014/09/magento-add-or-remove-js.html)

please check this.

i also same code remove js.

```
<action method="removeItem">
 <type>js</type><name>js/Yourjsname</name></action>
   </reference>
```